# How to calculate average of each column and the data in separate file?

Tags: awk

I would like to find the average of the first two columns in each file and divide the values (Column 2 / Column 1). Below shows the example of my intended output:

File1:

```
A B
1 2 
4 5 
7 8
```

File2:

```
A B 
2 3 
5 6 
8 9
```

Desired output:

```
File1 1.25
File2 1.125
```

Comment: `bash` is not a suitable language for  floating-point arithmetic.

Comment: @M.NejatAydin : I think the OP knows this, and this is the reason why he tagged the question _awk_  and not _bash_.

Comment: @SadStudent : We would expect that you at least show what you tried to solve this problem.

Comment: @user1934428 I don't think so. The question was tagged with `bash`, not with `awk`, at the time I wrote that comment.

Comment: I see! I hate it when these things are changed in a question later, in particular since the question itself does not give any hint about such important detail.

Answer (score 1):

Using awk:

```
awk 'NR>1 { tot1+=$1;tot2+=$2 } ENDFILE { print FILENAME" "tot2/tot1 }' file1 file2
```

Process lines that are greater than 1 (NR>1 - discount the header line). Use tot1 as variable for a running total of column 1 ($1) and use tot2 as a running total of the second field. At the end of processing each file, print the filename ( held in FILENAME) along with tot2/tot1